# Crystal Report without using datasource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I would like to know how to create a crystalreport without using a data source.
I googled a lot. But didn't find any solution.

My ultimate aim is to generate a pdf dynamically which is having 3 pages. and some fields in pdf will pass from code behind. So I thought to create a crystal report separately and save in my web project. After that pass the values to crystal report file from code behind and generate the pdf from it. (It will work that way?)

Comment: it's been a while but there used to be parameters you could define - also you can use old `DataSet` directly

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest me some links to create crystal report without db or the way you said?I dont have any data source related to this report.

Comment: just create a DataSet in the designer - you don't need a database to do so - after this you should be able to find this inside CRs import - if not just write the XML scheme somewhere to disk and import this (you can do so with a few lines of code - look at the documentation or just explore a bit with intellisense - I don't use CR anymore so I cannot really tell you every single step)

Comment: What do you mean without datasource...you are giving some input to the crystal report...that itself is a datasource

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to have your report without datasource.

1. Add parameters in the reports and send the value from the code behind to those parameters.
2. Add your own static data in your Crystal report.

Please go through these links for further clarifications and development.

[Add Report without dataset](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/176d6a49-e967-414a-a11a-2d3c4962cc2b/how-to-create-a-crystal-report-without-dataset-?forum=vscrystalreports)

[Add your own dataset](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-without-database.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values from your code to a CR report through parameters.

Check the .parameterFields() property of the CR report object. Values can be assigned to this array before displaying and/or printing your report.

Comment: Thanks But My question is how to create crystal report without using database

Comment: There is nothing in CR that forces you to have a database, except when going through the wizard. Just create a report from scratch, and do not add any datasource to it.